# cap(capistrano) output missing DEBUG INFO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I move my application to an other server,my (cap)capistrano exec is well but the output is different from before.

before -
Capistrano Version: 3.4.0 (Rake Version: 10.4.2)

```
" >> /deployment/temp/xx.sh
  INFO [0e2f8651] Finished in 0.021 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [7b2cf9d6] Running /usr/bin/env chmod u=rx,g=rx,o=rx /xx/temp/xxx.sh as xx@xxx
 DEBUG [7b2cf9d6] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod u=x,g=rx,o=rx /xx/temp/xxx
  INFO [7b2cf9d6] Finished in 0.018 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [57f78a45] Running /usr/bin/env sudo cp -f /xx/temp/xx.sh /etc/init.d/xxx as dx@xx
 DEBUG [57f78a45] Command: /usr/bin/env sudo cp -f /xx/temp/xxx.sh /etc/init.d/xxx
  INFO [57f78a45] Finished in 0.028 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [693eb1d8] Running /usr/bin/env sudo /sbin/chkconfig --add xxx as xxx@xxx
```

after - Capistrano Version: 3.6.1 (Rake Version: 10.4.2)

```
" >> /deployment/temp/xxxx.sh
    ✔ 03 xx@xxx 0.020s
      04 chmod u=xx,g=xx,o=xx /xxx/temp/xxx.sh
    ✔ 04 xx@xx 0.017s
      05 sudo cp -f /xxx/temp/xxxx.sh /etc/init.d/xxxx
```

I want the output like the first style. 
where can I config to solve it?

Comment: I see that is beacuse capistrano version >=3.5 use the default format airbrussh.   set :format, :pretty can change the format style.See the code diff  [link](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/1541/files)

Answer (score 0):

In `deploy.rb`, set the log level:

```
set :log_level, :info
```

Comment: I add
# encoding : utf-8
set :log_level, :info
set :format, :pretty
to my deploy.rb,but still show the second format

Comment: I see that is beacuse capistrano version >=3.5 use the default format airbrussh.